# Quantum transformation equivalent to Discrete Wavelet transform

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-fourier-transform

Suppose we have a matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &4 \\
1 &  4\\
\end{bmatrix}$, when applying the discrete wavelet transform to this matrix we get 4 parts i.e smooth part ($1\times 1$) matrix, 3 detail parts each of them being ($1\times 1$) matrices. Is there any quantum transformation that performs this task? Can somebody suggest? Is it in some way related to Fourier Transformation?

Comment: Could you expand a bit more?

Comment: what part do you want me to expand?

Comment: You seem to be using non-standard terminology with detail parts etc so follow through with your example A.

Answer (score 2):

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9909014) by Andreas Klappenecker might be a good starting point. The paper spearheaded quantum wavelet transforms and so-called wavelet packet transforms. A wavelet packet transforms yields an iterated decomposition into high-pass and low-pass filtered signals, whereas a wavelet transform only further decomposes the low-pass filtered and down-scaled version of the signal.